# How does the Bombardier CSeries compare to existing single-aisle jet-liners?

Tags: aircraft-design, airbus, bombardier, airbus-a220

With news breaking in that [Airbus will acquire a large part of Bombardier's CSeries program](https://news.google.com/news/story/dthp5hUcni1YDbMB205_tqQnTl5uM?hl=en), I'm curious, just how much better are the new planes from Bombardier compared to single aisle planes like the 737 and 320 series?

Aircraft manufacturers drop superficial numbers in their press announcements like, "10% more fuel efficient", etc. It would be great to hear some more technical differences / flying characteristics etc.

Comment: Better is a very subjective term; what do you mean by it?

Comment: [This site](http://www.airliners.net/forum/viewtopic.php?t=1355819) lists the CS300's consumption at 1950 kg/h. For the 737-600, the same list gives 2200 kg/h. Both planes seem to have similar MTOWs and service ranges. For the A319ceo, the same source gives also about 2200 kg/h. With a 15% fuel burn save over the ceo, I suppose the A319neo would burn about 1870 kg/hr (though the A319neo has larger MTOW and  range than the CS300). The A319neo seems to be difficult to sell.

Comment: @bjelleklang I guess that's what I'm trying to understand. The press reports it as "better". I'm trying to understand just how it is better. :-)

Comment: IMO, the biggest advantage of the CSeries over the 737 and 320 is its ability to operate out of airports with steep approaches, like London City Airport. http://economyclassandbeyond.boardingarea.com/2017/04/26/bombardier-obtains-cseries-cs100-certification-for-steep-approaches-featuring-lcy/